# I have path Manipulation issue. The following code is placed in Page_load method of ASPx page + VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
If Request.QueryString("ID") = "" Then
                folderDirectory = Global.FileUpload.GetFolderDirectory(Request.QueryString("TFID"))

                If Not File.Exists(folderDirectory + fileName) Then
                    If Not Directory.Exists(folderDirectory) Then
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderDirectory)
                    End If

                    Dim bufferSize As Integer = Me.fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength
                    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
                    '  write the byte to disk
                    Using fs As New FileStream(Path.Combine(folderDirectory, fileName), FileMode.Create)
                        Dim bytes As Integer = Me.fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                        '  write the bytes to the file stream
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes)
                    End Using
                Else
                    CallOnComplete("error", "", "Error uploading '" & fileName & "'. File has been exists!")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

But Fortify scan report for the above sample code shows `Path Manipulation` issue as high. I Need help to modify above code so that it can pass fortify scan
It is showing me error at folderDirectory

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when your code works inside a web application you don't have the liberty to use the full file system as you do on your local PC. Any kind of 'Path Manipulation' is suspicious.
You should try to recode your works using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.
Pay particular attention to this warning

```
For security reasons, the AspEnableParentPaths property has a default value set to FALSE.  
Scripts will not have access to the physical directory structure unless AspEnableParentPaths  
is set to TRUE.
```